# I get an error on the source folder (src) when a single class in one of the packages has an error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, src

Is there any way I can still run programs while having an error on another program in another package on the same source folder? Is there a way to create different source folders for different packages? How do I get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the situation is, but if it's a localized problem, you could simply comment out those parts of the code.